# Compute the singular homology groups of $S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

How do I go about computing the singular homology groups of $S^1$?

Anything to get me started or a full answer is appreciated.

EDIT: I've realised that while this is a simple question, there are various ways to get the answer, as Johannes Hahn has suggested. In particular, I'm looking into attempting to do calculations on singular homology groups. How will that look like? (Is it very similar to doing the calculations to find the simplicial homology groups and then do a slight change of notation?)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to compute the singular homology without using an isomorphism to some other homology theory (such as simplicial, Cech, ...), then the standard way is to use Mayer--Vietoris.  You decompose $S^1$ into the union of two intervals, each overlapping near their two endpoints, and use the fact that intervals are contractible (and hence have the homology of a point).

Answer (score 3):

The standard way of doing it would be to first prove standard theorems about singular homology (Eilenberg-Steenrod-Axioms, Mayer-Vietoris, suspension isomorphism, ...). Then one can easily (that is easy with all these theorems) prove that $H_n(S^m;A) = \begin{cases} A & n=0 \vee n=m \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Oooor: One gets ones hands dirty and actually calculates. This is clearly the less preferable way and heavily depends on what is already known and what is not.

Oooor: One knows about the several other ways to define homology (cellular, simplicial, Cech, ...) and that they all give the same result. In that case one can use the easier to calculate homologies.

Johannes Hahn.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions that there are various methods of doing this problem. If say I want to get my hands dirty and actually calculate, what kind calculations will it be like? (Maybe I should include this as an edit.)

Comment: Concerning your question if it doing computations with singular homology is similar to computing with simplicial homology: Sometimes, but in general no. The reason is that even for very nice spaces the singular chain complex consists of infinitely many infinite-dimensional modules whereas finite simplicial complexes give rise to finitely many finite-dimensional modules such that one can use all the linear algebra one wants (and has... depending on the coefficient you want to use, but in general you work with fields or $\mathbb{Z}$ or something like this)

Comment: Since we're not told what tools are available, I favor your idea of supposing that the suspension isomorphism is available. Calculating the homology of a $2$-point discrete space seems a tolerable task.

Comment: Is there a simple nice example where calculation with singular homology is different from calculation with simplicial homology?

Answer (score 1):

You could triangulate $S^1$ (use the border of a 2-simplex), then compute the simplicial homology of that simplex, and then use that simplicial and singular homology agree.

Or, you could calculate the $\pi_{1}$, and use Hurewicz theorem.